# How do I revert from FRF50 back to ERE27?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I got all excited with the leaked froyo update.zip that hit the net a few days ago, and installed it on my phone.  Since then I've had many issues, the big one being ADB not discovering my phone.  I'd like to revert my phone back, but can't find a signed update.zip on the nets that will do it.

Does anyone know how I can revert my N1 from FRF50, back to ERE27?  My phone is not rooted.

Comment: Have you updated the Android SDK to the latest version?  This comes with new ADB drivers so this might solve the problem of ADB not discovering your Froyo-ed Nexus One.  I'm running FRF50 and ADB is working OK for me.

Comment: Note that downgrades are not supported by Android. This means that if you revert to an older version of Android, you will have to erase all data from your phone.

Comment: Everything is updated.  I even tried different computers, and reinstalling everything fresh.  The computer sees the phone as portable media, but will not recognize is as an Android Phone.  Yes, I'm running debugging on my phone.  I also have a second N1 that's still running 2.1 and it works fine with ADB.

Comment: [Don't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46035/should-i-remove-tags-that-dont-contribute-to-categorizing-the-question/46037#46037) [tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43879/anti-tags-valid-use-or-not) [not-programming-related.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag/10222#10222) @aardvark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, clearly no one in this space can help me. I sent a letter to Google, and this one the response.

> Hello Brenton,
>
> Thank you for your email. I understand you'd like to revert to the old
>   update.
>
> Unfortunately, you cannot revert back to old update. We're unable to
>   provide release dates for Android 2.2, but please rest assured that we're
>   working hard to provide the update as soon as possible.
>
> You'll get an automatic notification when the over-the-air (OTA) update is
>   available for your device. For more information on installing the OTA
>   update, please visit
>   http://www.google.com/support/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173738
>
> We appreciate your patience.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Shital
>   The Google Team

Comment: Maybe you didn't get a response since your question isn't programming related.